# conditional statement with awk

Tags: linux, ubuntu, awk

I'm new with linux

I'm trying to get logs between two dates with gawk.

this is my log

```
Oct 07 11:00:33 abcd
Oct 08 12:00:33 abcd
Oct 09 14:00:33 abcd
Oct 10 21:00:33 abcd
```

I can do it when  both `start` and `end` date are sent

but I have problem when `start` or `end` date or `both` are not sent

and I don't know how to check it .

I've written below code but it has syntax error .

```
sudo gawk -v year='2022'  -v start='' -v end='2022:10:08 21:00:34' '
 BEGIN{ gsub(/[:-]/," ", start); gsub(/[:-]/," ", end) }
{ dt=year" "$1" "$2" "$3; gsub(/[:-]/," ", dt) }
if(start && end){mktime(dt)>=mktime(start) && mktime(dt)<=mktime(end)}
else if(end){mktime(dt)<=mktime(end)} 
else if(start){mktime(dt)>=mktime(start)} ' log.txt
```

How can I modify this code ?

Comment: `dt=year" "$1" "$2" "$3` results in e.g. `2022 Oct 07 11 00 33` which is not a supported datespec for `mktime()`, according to gawk.info it needs to be `"YYYY MM DD HH MM SS [DST]"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd write:

```bash
gawk -v end="Oct 10 12:00:00" '
    function to_epoch(timestamp,     n, a) {
        n = split(timestamp, a, /[ :]/)
        return mktime(strftime("%Y", systime()) " " month[a[1]] " " a[2] " " a[3] " " a[4] " " a[5])
    }

    BEGIN {
        split("Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec", m)
        for (i=1; i<=12; i++) month[m[i]]=i

        if (start) {_start = to_epoch(start)} else {_start = 0}
        if (end)   {_end   = to_epoch(end)}   else {_end   = 2**31}
    }

    { ts = to_epoch($0) }
    _start <= ts && ts <= _end
' log.txt
```

You'll pass the `start` and/or `end` variables with the same datetime format as appears in the log file.

Answer (score 1):

This would be easier with [dateutils](http://www.fresse.org/dateutils), e.g.:

```
<infile dategrep -i '%b %d %H:%M:%S' '>Oct 08 00:00:00' |
        dategrep -i '%b %d %H:%M:%S' '<Oct 09 23:59:59'
```

Output:

```
Oct 08 12:00:33 abcd
Oct 09 14:00:33 abcd
```